# F# take subsequence of a sequence

Tags: f#, sequences

I need to define a function, which takes a sequence 
        [image]
and integers `i` and `n` as parameters and  returns sub list or sub sequence of this seq, defined as followed:

[image]
.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write:

```
let subSeq i n = Seq.skip i >> Seq.take n
```

Which is used, e.g.:

```
let result = subSeq 5 10 [0..20]
```