# How to get a sublist or a subsequence in F#

Tags: f#, sequences

I am trying to truncate this sequence like you can do with arrays in F#

```
let sublist sequ (i:int) (n:int) = 
    let item = Seq.item(n-i) sequ
    let start = Seq.item i sequ
    let ending = Seq.item n sequ
    Seq.truncate(item) (seq{start..ending})

sublist [|25..92|] 5 10
```

like it can be done here

```
 Array.sub [|5..20|] 3 10
```

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093543/f-take-subsequence-of-a-sequence

Comment: yeah that works too but I don't understand the meaning of >> 
but thanks

Comment: @TheWololo `>>` and `<<` are function composition operators.  They avoid the requirement to supply an explicit argument to the first function and then pipe it to the second.  They can make function defined using them a little bit more succinct.  See this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1904063/5438433

Comment: @TheInnerLight thanks a lot mate, they are quite handy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to write the expected results.

You can use `take` and `skip` as in the linked answer in the comments:

```
let sublist sequ (i:int) (n:int) = 
    sequ |> Seq.skip i |> Seq.take (n-1)
```

Notice that if you are dealing with arrays you can use array slices:

```
[|25..92|].[5..10]  
> 
val it : int [] = [|30; 31; 32; 33; 34; 35|]

[|5..20|].[3..10]
 > 
 val it : int [] = [|8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15|]
```

Comment: how would that look like exactly?

Comment: Thanks mate, this has really helped me a lot